# Updating a single column in a file based on some condition

Tags: linux, bash

I have a input file that has two records and each record is pipe delimited.

Input file : /omega/inputfiles/feeds.txt

```
SALES|2015-12-14
PROFILES|2015-11-27
```

To a shell script , I will pass a dynamic date in 'YYYY-mm-dd" format . if that dynamic date is not equal to date value in feeds.txt then I need to replace that date value in feeds.txt with dynamic date .

Lets say if I pass dynamic date as '2015-12-14' then this file needs to updated as below

```
SALES|2015-12-14
PROFILES|2015-12-14
```

I wrote the below script , but I don't know how to replace a field of a record in a file based on a condition

```
replacing_dt=$1

RAW_DIR_PATH=/omega/inputfiles/

          while read feed_line ; do               

                 raw_dir_latest_upt_dt=`echo $feed_line | cut -d '|' -f 2`

                       if [ $raw_dir_latest_upt_dt != $replacing_dt]

                          then

                            #Code to replace the date available in file with replacing_dt


                        fi 

          done < $RAW_DIR_PATH/feeds.txt
```

I execute this file as bash /omega/code/file_update.sh   2015-12-14

Could somebody help me on adjusting this code to meet my requirement

Comment: Is there a mistake in your example? 24th instead of 14th?

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand what you need to do, but given the fact that you want the second column to be the date you provided as an argument, there is no need to really do the check. Just read the file with `awk`, print the first column, then print date argument.

Comment: yes, it was a mistake, I edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why bother checking, replace is enough for your situation:

```
replacing_dt=$1

RAW_DIR_PATH=/omega/inputfiles/
awk -v dt="$replacing_dt" -F '|' '{print $1 FS dt}' "$RAW_DIR_PATH/feeds.txt"
```